# probability of joint continuous random variables

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a joint pdf:

$f(x,y) = e^{-(x+y)}, 0 < x < \infty , 0 < y < \infty$

And I'm looking to find the following probability:

$P(X+Y<2)$

As I understand it, I can rearrange this as:

$P(X<2-Y)$

I'm confused as to how I would set up the bounds of integration for my double integral. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Your joint pdf is not normalized. Are you sure it does not range up to $\infty$? Also your $y$ bound should not depend on $y$ and your $x$ bound should not depend on $x.$ The bounds on the inner integral may (and do in this case) depend on the outer integration variable.

Comment: you are right, I confused the area of interest with another problem, thank you

Comment: It should be $\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}f\,dy\,dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a good idea here is to make a sketch of your integration domain here $\mathbb{R}^2$. Draw the limits for your integration ($x = 2-y$) and realize which part of the plane you are interested in integrating.

Then choose the integration limits. If you are integrating $x$ first. What is the lower bound will take as a function of $y$ , what is the maximum so that you remain your area of interest? After integrating $x$, can y take any possible value?.

Drawing a sketch is the best way to build the intuition.